# Почему бывает утечка у arguments

Tags: javascript, v8

Приветствую.
Наткнулся на интересную [статью](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) о плохих практиках для оптимизации кода в JS движках.
Заинтересовало почему течёт `arguments` при описанных случаях и почему `Function#apply` - исключение.
Особенно интересно почему будет утечка при `Array#slice`, ведь при передаче примитивов будет возвращена никак не связанная копия.
Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: @Visman, видимо бывает, см. статью.

Comment: [статься от одного из разработчиков v8 на эту тему](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/11/02/crankshaft-vs-arguments-object.html).

Answer (score 5):

При чем тут утечка, если статья про "убийц оптимизации"?

На самом деле все просто.

```
function foo(x, y, z) {
  bar(arguments);
  console.log(x, y, z);
}

foo(1, 2);
```

Давайте поиграем в игру. Вы - компилятор js. Чему будут равны переменные x, y и z в конце? Без функции bar узнать этого не получится.

Теперь еще одна задачка:

```
function bar(a) {
  a[0] = 6;
  a[1] = 7;
  a[2] = 8;
}

function foo(x, y, z) {
  bar(arguments);
  console.log(x, y, z);
}
```

Что теперь можно сказать? Вывод на консоль все еще не определен!

Объект arguments делает функцию очень сложной для компиляции - для того, чтобы узнать хоть что-то, надо копать очень глубоко. Поэтому проще даже не пытаться оптимизировать такие функции.

---

Решение же, на самом деле, куда проще чем написано в той статье.

### `"use strict"`

Comment: Да, это я знаю, но что по поводу `Array#slice` и `Function#apply`?

Comment: @Other это такие же внешние функции, что и остальные. Их могут, к примеру, заманкипатчить.

Comment: Даже если не манкипатчить это будет неоптимизируемо. Для передачи arguments как параметра нужно его матрелиазовать (в оптимизированной версии `arguments` вообще отсутсвует, значения хранятся в стэке (см. статью про v8)). Создание объекта arguments может быть дорогой операцией (если код является "горячим"). "use strict" устраняет только некоторые проблемы с arguments (убирает необходимость обновлять значение в arguments при изменении соответсвующего именованного аргумента).

Comment: Function.prototype.apply это особый случай (у него, кстати, тоже есть подводные камни). *(Далее только мои предположения)* Полагаю что если  `apply` вызывается для arguments то можно просто скопировать  стек текущей функци в вызываемую, разумеется нужно будет изменить некоторые значения (прим. текущий this), но это будет быстрее чем создавать объект `arguments` (его потом ещё и удалять придётся (gc)).